# Do we need all files and folders while re-desiging Nuxt JS site?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

Is it necessary to have all files while re-designing website?

Like, I've designed a site with Nuxt JS, published it, now if in future I want to make some changes, do I need all files back that I started with? Like all node modules, pages folder, components folder, everything? Asking because there are tons of files in total.

A recent case happened with me is, I wanted to do some changes in my recent Nuxt JS site, but I missed "pages" folder, however I have "dist" folder. Is there any way I can like recover "pages" folder from my final production site?

Also, what will be best practice to manage Nuxt JS projects? Any tips, tricks will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To develop on a NuxtJS site, you need the directories and files listed in the Nuxt guide's [Directory Structure](https://nuxtjs.org/guide/directory-structure) section. The files you **don't** need for future development are the files in the [default `.gitignore`](https://github.com/nuxt/nuxtjs.org/blob/master/.gitignore) that `create-nuxt-app` generates for you, including the `dist` directory and the `node_modules` directory.

The `dist` directory can be regenerated from your source code using `npm run generate` and `node_modules` from running `npm install` if you have `package.json` or `package-lock.json` file. Anything that can be generated from some other file(s), you don't need to keep.

- Is there any way I can like recover "pages" folder from my final production site?

  - Unfortunately not.
- What will be best practice to manage NuxtJS projects?

  - Not sure what you mean with "manage", but if you don't use git yet, then git.